# Periodically reload a page in Rails 4 using Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have a page that displays some status information. This page runs on a PC without any user input and needs to refresh each few minutes.

I can get it to refresh with the meta tag but this seems crude. It forces the refresh of all the assets and causes that ugly flicker. Turbolinks does a nice job everywhere else with smarter page loading. Can I get this to work with an automatic refresh?

I'd appreciate any advice on how I can make this work better.

Comment: Why do you need a refresh? Can't you implement some ajax or even prettier solutions?

Comment: I've never done that before. I wouldn't even know where to start. If you could point me in the right direction, that would be helpful.

Comment: `$.ajax('/your/url').succes(function() { // do something with the feedback})`, just google for periodical updates through ajax. Or lookup a tutorial in building a chat.

Comment: Thank you. After some Googling, I'm fairly sure I'm pretty close to getting this working.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I recently used under Turbolinks 5.  Had to add some variables to stop it from reloading once the user browsed away from the page, etc.

```
<script>
  if(!window.reloadTimer) {
    var SECONDS = 30;
    window.reloadTimer=setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("Reload!");
      window.reloadTimer=undefined;
        Turbolinks.visit(location.toString(),{action: "replace"});
    }, SECONDS * 1000);
    document.addEventListener("turbolinks:visit",function() {clearTimeout(window.reloadTimer);window.reloadTimer=undefined;});
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Worked very well, this is a new approach of using turbolinks to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
    var SECONDS = 5;
    setTimeout(function(){
        Turbolinks.enableTransitionCache(true);
        Turbolinks.visit(location.toString());
        Turbolinks.enableTransitionCache(false);
    }, SECONDS * 5);
});
```